# Disable system notifications in iOS app

Tags: ios, notifications

I'm developing an app with a mode that require to be used without any touch interaction.
So when the user push "start", the app would disable some system notifications, the ones that ask the user to interact.

I think about these ones:

- 10%-20% battery alert
- wifi alert
- no service alert

Is there a way to prevent these alert in a certain mode (as a "no light-off" mode exists) ?

Comment: I think not possible programmatically, unless jail break